# Using recompose utility as element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, recompose

I want to use recompose utility functions as react element, so that I can use them in JSX as hoc.

```js
const enhancedInput = props => {
  return (<OnlyUpdateForKeys keys={['name']}>
              <Input
                id="name"
                value={props.name}
                onBlur={props.handleNameBlur}
                onChange={props.updateName}
                type="text"
                className="validate"
                placeholder="Enter Component Name"
              />
            </OnlyUpdateForKeys>)
}
```

This is what I have tried till now, but it utterly fails.

```js
import { onlyUpdateForKeys } from 'recompose';

export const OnlyUpdateForKeys = ({ keys, children }) => {
  return onlyUpdateForKeys([...keys])(children)(children.props);
};

export default OnlyUpdateForKeys;
```

because children is a symbol and react-element instance and not a class/function.

```
react.development.js:368 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined
at Component (react.development.js:368)
at ShouldUpdate (Recompose.esm.js:558)
at OnlyUpdateForKeys (recomposeComponent.js:4)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:14324)
```

Can somebody guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onlyUpdateForKeys([...keys])` higher-order component expects React *component* as an argument, while `children` is React *element*:

```
onlyUpdateForKeys([...keys])(children)
```

It would be workable like:

```
export const OnlyUpdateForKeys = ({ keys, children }) => {
  const EnhancedChild = onlyUpdateForKeys([...keys])(props => children);
  return <EnhancedChild/>;
};
```

But it doesn't make sense because it doesn't prevent child component from being updated. `OnlyUpdateForKeys` is created on each `EnhancedInput` render. `Input` is rendered every time `EnhancedInput` is rendered too, because `children` are rendered any way - otherwise they wouldn't be available as `props.children`.

While `onlyUpdateForKeys` is supposed to be used as:

```
const EnhancedInput = onlyUpdateForKeys(['name'])(props => (
  <Input ... />
))
```

It's shorter and more efficient than `OnlyUpdateForKeys` utility component.